# Must an element be visible in order to "load" event listener to work?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, opera, addeventlistener, image-loading

In my document, there are two svg images: the preview and the result. The result image is computed based on the preview image; I switch between them by adding/removing class `hidden-display`, which is further affected by css like this:

```
.hidden-display {
display: none;
}
```

This seems to be working well.

While the result image is being computed, I want to hide the preview image and show only a progress bar; once the result image is loaded, I want it to be displayed and hide the progress bar. Here's the code that works; see especially the two occurrences of function `showResult()`:

```
function resultImageLoaded(event) {
    console.log("Inside add event listener function");
    resultImage.removeEventListener("load", resultImageLoaded, false);
    //showResult();    // Doesn't work if uncommented
    hideProgressBar();
    console.log("End event listener");
}

function submitChanges() {
    showProgressBar();

    var inputData = getInputString();
    var uri = "./ResultImage.cshtml?inputData=" + encodeURIComponent(inputData);

    resultImage.data = uri;
    resultImage.addEventListener("load", resultImageLoaded, false);

    hidePreview();
    showResult();    // Doesn't work if commented out
}
```

**Problem:** While the code above works, it doesn't do exactly what I wanted: it hides the preview, shows the result and only then the event listener function is called, which hides the progress bar.

If I comment out `showResult()` in the function `submitChanges()` and uncomment it in the event listener function instead, the listener function `resultImageLoaded(event)` is never called - probably meaning the result image is never loaded. This leads me to suspicion that invisible elements don't trigger the "load" event listeners, but that seems strange.

I tested this in two browsers - Internet Explorer 11 and Opera 33.0. In IE, everything works as expected and the event listener is called, but in Opera I encountered the problem described above.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure but try `visibility:hidden` instead of `display:none`

Comment: @Rajesh Strangely, this works, but unless there is another option, I can't use this solution as it completely messes up my formatting - while `display` element is removed out of the flow of HTML, `visibility` element is not. I'll try to find a workaround. If you elaborate your solution in an answer, I'll gladly mark it as accepted. Thank you.

Comment: A simple workaround is setting height and width to `0px;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per our discussion, `visibility:hidden` is solving the event issue.
Following is a example addressing your second problem, UI spacing.

```js
function registerEvent() {
  document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log("Test");
  });
}

function addClass(str) {
  document.getElementById("test").className = str;
}
```

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 2px solid gray;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
.display {
  display: none
}
.hidden {
  visibility: hidden
}
.invisible {
  visibility: hidden;
  height: 0px;
  width: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.show {
  visibility: visible;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">0</div>
<div id="test1">1</div>


<button onclick="addClass('display')">Display</button>
<button onclick="addClass('hidden')">Hidden</button>
<button onclick="addClass('invisible')">Invisible</button>
<button onclick="addClass('show')">Show</button>
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

In fact, in Opera one cannot register an event on a node with display:none. Since working with visibility may easily mess up the formatting it may be a solution work with opacity like:

```
.hide {
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -20;
}

.show {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Just toggle this two classes on the div's you want to show/hide. If the user needs to interact with something in the presented div you will have to add the z-index (as above). This also opens the possibility to add some nice transitions.

Comment: Like `visibility`, changing `opacity` doesn't remove the element from the flow, so you'd have the same problems with messing up formatting, wouldn't you...?

Comment: @Amos M. Carpenter `opacity` doesn't removes the element from the flow, thats true. In addition it also has no effect on the size of any element, we are in full control of the formatting. The assumption here (and maybe there, the question has to be extended) is, that we have two ore more elements laying over each other, `position: absolute` and we switch the visibility from the preview pic to the loading pic to the final pic. Basically `opacity`solves the aked question the same way as `visibility` but maybe in a more elegant way.